# Universal Microsoft Word document parser without Word installation

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word

In order to parse : Microsoft Word 97/2003 (.doc) & Microsoft Word 2007/2010 (.docx) using C# and WPF without Word installation, I need to know if someone can give me a serious library to use in order to achieve that.

Technically I iterate throught ZipEntry elements like that :

```
foreach (string file in _listPathFiles)
        {
            using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file))
            {
                try
                {
                    zip.ToList().ForEach(entry =>
                    {
                        if (entry.FileName.EndsWith(".doc") ||
                            entry.FileName.EndsWith(".docx"))
                        {
                            // Extract file into disk
                            entry.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(entry.FileName);
                            entry.Extract(baseStoragePath);

                            // Get data from file with Parser
                            string filePath = baseStoragePath + entry.FileName;


                            // Remove extracted filess
                            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                            {
                                File.Delete(filePath);
                                Console.WriteLine("Delete : " + filePath);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Fail to unzip Exception : " + e.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure that I can use ZipEntry directly to get the document, may be I will have to unzip it before parsing ?!

And my goal is to get data located after a "Heading 1" Microsoft Word style, so the library should be able to get this kind of properties.

Libraries ideas and code samples are welcome..

Comment: How about NPOI?  http://npoi.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

[GroupDocs.Parser for .NET](https://products.groupdocs.com/parser/net) can be used in your case for extracting the text from Word documents without installing MS Word. The extraction can be performed line by line or at once.

```
// extracting all the text 
WordsTextExtractor extractor = new WordsTextExtractor("sample.docx");
Console.Write(extractor.ExtractAll());

// OR

// Extract text line by line
string line = extractor.ExtractLine();

// If the line is null, then the end of the file is reached
while (line != null)
{
      // Print a line to the console
      Console.Write(line);
      // Extract another line
      line = extractor.ExtractLine();
}
```

*Disclosure: I work as Developer Evangelist at GroupDocs.*

Answer (score -1):

Check out NPOI (A .NET Port of the Apache NOI API):
http://npoi.codeplex.com/

or

Download [OpenXML](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) SDK for reading Office Documents such as MS Word.

Comment: NPOI looking at the documentation doesn't seems to manage .doc files and OpenXML SDK like it means (.docx) doesn't work with .doc too..